# Can't figure out where function is going wrong

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file `IDlistfix`, which contains a list of youtube video IDs.  I'm trying to make a new text file, `newlist.txt`, which is the IDs in the first video with apostrophes around them and a comma in between the IDs.  This is what I've written to accomplish this:

```
n = open('IDlistfix','r+')
j = open('newlist.txt','w')
line = n.readline()

def listify(rd):
    return '\'' + rd + '\','

for line in n:
    j.write(listify(line))
```

This gives me an output of `','rUfg2SLliTQ` where I'd expect the output to be `'rUfg2SLliTQ',`.  Where is my function going wrong?

Comment: `rd.strip()` will get rid of newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to strip it of newlines:

```
j.write(listify(line.strip())) # Notice the call of the .strip() method on the String
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove trailing whitespace and return a formatted string:

```
n = open('IDlistfix','r+')
j = open('newlist.txt','w')
line = n.readline()

def listify(rd):
    # remove trailing whitespace
    rd = rd.rstrip()
    # return a formatted string
    # this is generally preferable to '+'
    return "'{0}',".format(rd)

for line in n:
    j.write(listify(line))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem must be in,

```
`return '\'' + rd + '\`','
```

because rd is ending with '/n'.
Remove the '/n' from rd and it should be fine

Answer (score 1):

Is a problem with change of line.

Change:

```
    for line in n:
        j.write(listify(line.replace('\n','')))
```